# Suggestions to get PostId and BlogId number from Blogger Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blogger

I want to get the postId and blogId number from **Blogger** using **JavaScript**. I have tried many methods to get the **blogId** && **postId** number but they all give me the result as **undefined**.

**blogId** && **BlogId** are protected by `expr:content`. Wish I didn't need access to them. 
Please help to get them into two variables.

```
x=blogId number;
y=postId number;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Blog-id**

From direct Blogger data tag:

```
var blogId = "<data:blog.blogId/>";
```

From meta tag:

```
var blogId = document.querySelector("[itemprop='blogId']").getAttribute("content");
```

**Post-id**

From first post:

```
var postId = document.querySelector("[itemprop='postId']").getAttribute("content");
```

An array with all posts data:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[itemprop='postId']"),
    identifiers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    identifiers[i] = elements[i].getAttribute("content");
}
```